# More elegant way of (un)checking in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I tried to entirely script this checkbox check / uncheck snippet of code in jQuery, but it did not have any success. Here is the jQuery/JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "check.xml",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find("check").each(function(){
                        $(xml).find("todo").each(function(){
                            var state = $(this).attr("state");
                            if (state == "true") {
                                document.getElementById($(this).attr("id")).checked = true;
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById($(this).attr("id")).checked = false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```

It's probably very possible to do the `document.getElementbyId(blablabla)....` using only jQuery. I tried this:

`($(this).attr("id")).prop("checked", true)`

But that didn't really work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: I tried that, but as commented, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the "#" in the selector:

```
var id = '#'+ $(this).attr("id");
```

Then you can do a one liner instead of the "if":

```
$(id).prop("checked", (state == "true"));
```

Comment: That is what I mean elegance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this (note the `#` symbol to get a element from the ID - same rules than CSS selectors) -

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$('#'+ id).prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Isn't that just `$(this).prop('checked',true)` ?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic No, Op is traversing over xml, not on actual DOM elements